Is there a way to run Gradle in a mounted WSL folder from Windows Command Line?
I have a Spring Boot project that runs fine on WSL. So I mount the folder into windows like
pushd \\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\mydir

Now I get on the z: but when I try to run the project with gradlew clean bootRun I get
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Gradle could not start your build.
> Could not create service of type BuildLifecycleController using ServicesProvider.createBuildLifecycleController().
   > Could not create service of type BuildModelController using VintageBuildControllerProvider.createBuildModelController().
      > Could not create service of type FileHasher using BuildSessionServices.createFileHasher().
         > java.io.IOException: Incorrect function

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 978ms

If I copy the folder to c: then it starts as expected as well. Is there a way to be able to run from the z: instead of having to copy everything to c:?

Add --full-stacktrace to show which function doesn't work.

Looks like file system doesn't support some operation.

Exact version of Windows, Gradle and the JDK used to execute Gradle?

Windows 11, Gradle 8.10.2, Java 23

@talexmovedtoCodidact I would agree so what should I do to fix it

Step one is find out what function is causing the problem. Post exceptions with full stack trace. Then you can try to convince gradle not to use it.

Did you try running Gradle inside WSL? Why can't just build on a Windows directory?

Yes as I said it runs every way except what is described but I dont want to maintain 2 copies of the file so my question is for exactly as described.
